# How to store checkbox values using localStorage? (react+hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, jsx, react-hooks

Here is my `Todolist` component, which contains a `List`, and all list items with checkboxes and with material list and checkboxes. Two props are passed: `todos` and `deleteTodo`.

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, deleteTodo}) => {
  return (
    <List>
      {todos.map((todo, index) => (
        <ListItem key={index.toString()} dense button>
         <Checkbox disableRipple/>
          <ListItemText key={index} primary={todo} />
          <ListItemSecondaryAction>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="Delete"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteTodo(index);
              }}
            >
              <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};
```

I figured out how to use local storage for storing the todos as an array, but have no idea how to store the checkbox values. Can somebody explain, what would be the strategy for that?

And here is the main app:

```
  const initialValue = () => {
    const initialArray = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    return JSON.parse(initialArray);
  };

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    const json = JSON.stringify(todos);
    localStorage.setItem("todos", json);
  });


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h2">
        Todos
      </Typography>

      <TodoForm
        saveTodo={todoText => {
          const trimmedText = todoText.trim();
          if (trimmedText.length > 0) {
            setTodos([...todos, trimmedText]);
          }
        }}
      />


      <TodoList
        todos={todos}
        deleteTodo={todoIndex => {
          const newTodos = todos.filter((_, index) => index !== todoIndex);
          setTodos(newTodos);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or directions, how to tackle this problem. Thx

Comment: you have to make the checkbox stateful. Seralize the state to localStorage the same way you do for todos. BTW what do you need checkbox for in terms of functionality

Comment: hello, @Pavan.
Checkbox is needed in order to mark todos which were done.

But making checkbox stateful - meaning additional useState? or It is possible to store it within todos state like that: todos =[{text: 'Todo1', checked: 'true/false'}, {text: 'Todo1', checked: 'true/false'}] Right?

Comment: I'd prefer the latter approach. Since it's the state of the todo item itself. It should be in the todo object only. You can have a key isCompleted: true/false and use it for hte checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use the `onChange` callback of the `Checkbox component`

e.g. `<Checkbox disableRipple onChange={(e)=> onCheckboxChange(e.event.target) />` (and whatever params you need)

and pass it up to your parent component through a prop, e.g.

`const TodoList = ({ todos, deleteTodo, onCheckboxChange}) => {`

You can then store the value in local storage the parent component.
There may be a more elegant approach